# Dynamodb update (Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0'))

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Params:

```
 {
        "TableName": "xxxxxxx",
        "Key": {
            "userId": {
                "S": "test"
            }
        },
        "UpdateExpression": "SET sent.#assignmentType = :newHomeworks",
        "ExpressionAttributeNames": {
            "#assignmentType": "books"
        },
        "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
            ":newHomeworks": [
                {
                    "M": {
                        "homeworkId": {
                            "S": "homework"
                        },
                        "userIds": {
                            "L": [
                                {
                                    "S": "test1"
                                },
                                {
                                    "S": "test2"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "ReturnValues": "UPDATED_NEW"
    }
```

do you know why I'm getting this error? It is when I'm trying to update the item like that.
newHomeworks ormat is wrong? it should be an array of objects.Thank you!

I have inserted only the broken code,It's breaking after the "Update params" log, I tried to send the params in many ways but I cannot find an explanation, I don't know why I get this error.
I don't think it's something wrong  in updateHomeworkTable because it's working in other cases, only here it is breaking.
code:

```
async assignedHomework(
    userId: string,
    studentIds: any,
    homework: any,
    assignmentType: string
  ) {
    const userHomeworks = await this.reader.getUserFromDb(userId);
    if (userHomeworks?.sent) {
      if (userHomeworks.sent[assignmentType]) {
        for (const homeworkObj of userHomeworks.sent[assignmentType]) {
          if (homeworkObj.homeworkId === homework) {
            homeworkObj.userIds = Array.from(
              new Set([...homeworkObj.userIds, ...studentIds])
            );

            const updateExpression = "SET sent.#assignmentType = :newHomeworks";

            // Define attribute names and values
            const expressionAttributeNames = {
              "#assignmentType": assignmentType,
            };
            this.logger.debug("parameters", userHomeworks.sent[assignmentType]);

            // AICI NEW HOMEWORKS NU ARE TREBUII SA FIE ALTFEL?
            const expressionAttributeValues = {
              ":newHomeworks": marshall(userHomeworks.sent[assignmentType]),
            };
            this.logger.debug(
              "parameters after update",
              marshall(userHomeworks.sent[assignmentType])
            );
            return await updateHomeworkTable(
              this.tableName,
              userId.toString(),
              updateExpression,
              expressionAttributeNames,
              expressionAttributeValues,
              this.instance,
              this.logger
            );
          }
        }
        const updateExpression =
          "SET sent.#assignmentType = list_append(if_not_exists(sent.#assignmentType, :emptyList), :newHomework)";

        // Define attribute names and values
        const expressionAttributeNames = {
          "#assignmentType": assignmentType,
        };

        const expressionAttributeValues = {
          ":newHomework": {
            L: [
              {
                M: {
                  homeworkId: { S: homework },
                  userIds: { L: studentIds.map((id: string) => ({ S: id })) },
                },
              },
            ],
          },
          ":emptyList": { L: [] },
        };
        return await updateHomeworkTable(
          this.tableName,
          userId.toString(),
          updateExpression,
          expressionAttributeNames,
          expressionAttributeValues,
          this.instance,
          this.logger
        );
      } else {
  }
}
const updateHomeworkTable = async (
  tableName: string,
  userId: string,
  updateExpression: string,
  expressionAttributeNames: any,
  expressionAttributeValues: any,
  instance: any,
  logger: any
) => {
  // Create UpdateItem command input
  const params: UpdateItemCommandInput = {
    TableName: tableName,
    Key: {
      userId: { S: userId },
    },
    UpdateExpression: updateExpression,
    ExpressionAttributeNames: expressionAttributeNames,
    ExpressionAttributeValues: expressionAttributeValues,
    ReturnValues: "UPDATED_NEW",
  };

  logger.debug("Update params", params);
  await instance.send(new UpdateItemCommand(params));
  logger.debug("Update finished");
};
```

Update...
it shouldn't be something here ?
Like  ":newHomeworks":{L:[]}?

Comment: I'm not an expert in nodejs, so I might be missing something (and don't understand what this error message refers to...), but isn't `userIds: { L: studentIds.map((id: string) => ({ S: id })) },` wrong? An "L" says what follows should be a list, but it seems what follows is a map, not a list. Maybe you meant a list of maps?

Comment: Please log and share the `params`  of in your function.

Comment: The first piece of code represent the params.

Comment: And I think it is correct like this Nadav :"userIds": {
                            "L": [
                                {
                                    "S": "test1"
                                },
                                {
                                    "S": "test2"
                                }
                            ]